# Input validation for .NET web api in Http Get request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a Restful service using .net web API.

There are a few posts about input validation for the post request using model validation. However, I am wondering what is the best practice of doing the validation for Get request.

For example

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id, string type)
{
    // validation
    if (id <= 500 & id >= 0) {
        // invalid request
        throw new HttpResponseException();
    }
    // type validation
    if (type is not in a predefined allowed type list from database) {
        // throw validation error
    }
    // more validation ... ...
    // do something else
}
```

I would like to know what is the best place to put the validation logic in in .net web api framework.

**The id validation is just an example and the validation logic could go quite complicated for some cases.**

I don't want to create a class just for the id and put some custom validator attribute on the ID property. I think .net has a better support for that already.

Comment: Do you even need it? If the request is for `id 122334534` and there is no record in the database for that `id`, you would just return `404 Not Found` anyway...

Comment: If the validation is that basic, do it in the controller method

Comment: This is just an example, the validation logic could be complicated in some case.

Comment: Then explain what "complicated" is.

Comment: I updated the example a bit and hopefully that explain more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use route constraints for this parameter

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },                
            constraints: new { id = "@[1-500]+" } //this is not valid code. use correct regular expression to implement validation behavior you need.
        );
```

Answer on comment. What u mean - complicated vlidation? You asked about GET request and the siplest way is use the route constraint. Another way is ActiontFilter. For example

```
public class SomeFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
        string param = filterContext.ActionArguments["id"].ToString();
        //do some validation stuff here. for example data anotations
        var validator = new RangeAttribute(1, 500); //numeric range.
        if (validator.IsValid(Convert.ToInt64(param)));
            do valid//
        //if u need validate entire model from post request try 
        if (!filterContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            filterContext.Response = filterContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, filterContext.ModelState);
        }

    }
}
```

or google for "web api model validation"

Comment: How about some complicated validation?